# What's the alternative to ComponentDidMount in React Server Rendered Application?

Tags: reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I have created an isomorphic React application. Everything works fine till I was trying to put some animations on my elements. If it was a client-side rendering app, I would do that by writing the animation function and invoke the function in componentDidMount() component lifecycle method. But unfortunately, this method won't work for SSR.

How to invoke my animation function in this case? (tried componentWillMount already, it's not working)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Why would you want to invoke animation functionality when you render the component from the server? Only the client can use the animations in the first place.

Comment: See I have one div with text in it.     I want a text reveal animation on that text once it's loaded to DOM. How can I  achieve that ?

Comment: `componentWillMount` _is_ the alternative, but if it's not working for you, post some code.

Comment: @KevinRaoofi I'm doing so because the site needs to be Search Engine Optimized. Hence using React Server-side rendering. Also, I am using scroll magic and GSAP libraries for DOM element entry and exit animations. Without document selector, I cannot attach animations on those elements which is exactly not working on Server.

Comment: @AjayVarghese, please take a look at my answer. You cannot do animations on the server. You can generate whatever content you want for SEO, but it's not gonna have animations on it until you call `ReactDOM.hydrate()` on it from the client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By design, no lifecycle methods should be invoked when rendered by the server (except [`componentWillMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)). This is because server side rendering is primarily for displaying site layout before data can be fully loaded and cannot really help for client side animations.

To get lifecycle methods to work on the client, simply use `ReactDOM.hydrate()`, [which is specifically designed to be used with server rendered content](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate) using the same component on the client. This way, `componentDidMount` and all other life cycle methods will work as expected while still containing the server rendered content.

If you don't want to do this, and you *just* want to use React to generate HTML from the server, you should probably consider using a regular templating language, instead. However, if you still want to call animations without using React from the client, you should try to make your animation work with pure CSS animations.